# How can i get array indexOf element includes value

Tags: javascript

How can i get array indexOf element includes value Like

```
var a = ["one","two","xx?ee"]; 

a.indexOf("?"); //i want to get indexOf element xx?ee
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Some general advice: Divide your problem into smaller solvable problems. For example here you could ask: 1. How to find out if a string contains a certain character and 2. How can i find or filter elements from an array based on a certain condition. Then you would be able to solve that on your own for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex) and [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/includes)

```js
var a = ["one","two","xx?ee"]; 

var ndx = a.findIndex(e => e.includes("?"));

console.log(ndx);
```

*Keep in mind that this will return the first match only.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`. This code will return an array , assuming that there can be multiple words wich contains `?`. So this aray will contain the index of all those words.

```js
var a = ["one", "two", "xx?ee", "11?ee"];


function getIndex(key) {
  return a.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (curr.includes(key)) {
      acc.push(index)
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])

}

console.log(getIndex('?'))
```